# react setState sets to string instead of object

Tags: json, api, reactjs, setstate

I am trying to fetch a big json file when the webpage has been loaded and then update react state with that data.

Currently, I have this code

```
get(url) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   req.open('GET', url);
   req.onload = () => req.status === 200 ? resolve(req.response) : reject(Error(req.statusText));
   req.onerror = (e) => reject(Error(`Network Error: ${e}`));
   req.send();
 });
```

}

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.get('https://x.com/data/tool.json').then((response) =>{
    this.setState({"sections" : response});
    console.log(this.state);
  }).catch((err) =>{
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

The code sets sections to a sting as shown in the screenshot instead of the actual json object.

[react setstate problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3scY.png)

How can I initialize state with the fetched json.

Comment: Did you try `JSON.parse` the string ?

Comment: You need to use JSON.parse to parse the string.

Comment: I have tried that many tmes. Also tried JSON.stringify first to ensure everything go right bu no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly I would recommend using the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) library instead of Promises and XMLHttpRequest. If you need to support IE 11 and below, you can use a [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch)

Sticking with your code though, at no point do you appear to use `JSON.parse` on your `response`, to turn the JSON string you get back into a JavaScript object.

```
this.setState({"sections" : JSON.parse(response)});
```

This would be much easier and cleaner with `fetch` though I feel,

```
componentDidMount(){
  fetch('https://abx.com/data/tool.json').then(response =>{
    if (!response.ok) throw Error('Response not ok')

    return response.json(); // This is built in JSON.parse wrapped as a Promise
  }).then(json => {
    this.setState({"sections" : json});
  }).catch(err =>{
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I have reinstalled babel-loader after which your code worked perfectly. I don't know why yarn installed binaries don't work as expected.